# ng.Net Template in Visual Studio is very slow

Tags: .net, angularjs, visual-studio, templates, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use the ng.net template (in visual studio 2013) to build a web app, but it is very slow. Every time i try to access any page it takes for ever.
I haven't done any modification to the project, just create new and start.
[image: calls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late to answer this question but I just came across the same problem and after putting some time found the cause. I thought, it would be nice to share it to save much time for the other guys.

The reason why the project is super slow being the DB connection. This template is using code first entity framework mode, so it tries to connect to the database and once it can't it waits for the timeout.

In the `web.config` file , there is a connection string called `applicationDB`. Set the connection string to a valid one then it gets fast.